# How does whatsapp determine country of the user without asking for location details?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, core-location

When signing up for WhatsApp, you need to enter your phone number. WhatsApp already knows (somehow) the country you are in and pre-selects that country for you, so you only need to **confirm** that.

[image: whatsapp phonenumber signup]

For the record, whatsapp does **not** ask for permission to access your location, but they still know it (vaguely, maybe). How is this?

Comment: They may use an IP address location database service, like http://www.iplocation.net/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually like this:

```
[[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode] uppercaseString];
```

in combination with a dictionary found on the web. I've open sourced the code, so with that, all you have to do is call one of the 2 methods and you're set :)

https://github.com/basdvries/BDVCountryNameAndCode

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
```

That will work for the vast majority of people who are in their own country, and haven't set their locale to some random other country.

Comment: No I don't think that's it. I found something else that's interesting but I can't test it since I'm not officially enrolled as an Apple developer, but I found this solution elsewhere: `    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
    CTCarrier *carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
    
    NSLog(@"country code is: %@", carrier.mobileCountryCode);
`